# Mock Hibernate @Entity with preset data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Hibernate makes its magic with reflection and init @Entity with data when it fetches data from DB. So I don't need to add setters or a constructor to init my data.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "products")
    public class Product implements Serializable {
        private integer id;
        private String name;
    }


    @Repository
    public interface ProductsRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {
        @Query("FROM #{#entityName} p where p.id = :id")
        Product findById(integer id);
    }
```

Fun starts when you make a unit test for some Service that deals with JpaRepository. I want to mock the repo to return mocked Product **with test data**

```java
    @Service
    public class MyAwesomeService {
        @Autowired
        private ProductsRepository productsRepository;

        public void returnProductName(Long productId) {
            Product product = productRepository.findById(productCode);
            return product.getName();
        }
    }
    // The test will look like
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    public class ProductsDeliveryTest {

        @InjectMocks
        private MyAwesomeService myAwesomeService;

        @Mock
        private ProductsRepository productsRepository;

        @Test
        public void test() {
            String productId = 1L;
            Product product = new Product()   // here I need to init Product with data      
            doReturn(productBookingFields)
                    .when(productsRepository)
                    .findById(productId);

            String name = myAwesomeService.returnProductName(productId);
            assertThat(name).isEqualTo("Test Product");
        }
    }
```

So I could

- add a constructor for the `Product` where I will init fields
- or make Product as JavaBean and use setters to init my data

The problem is - I **need them only for the tests** and it doesn't look like a good idea when I change my code to make my tests work.

Is there a more elegant way how can I mock Entity with preset data?

Comment: I also looked at `lombok.builder` but it's also overhead that I don't really need for the code itself.

Comment: You could also initialize the data with reflection. Not recommending it, but it's a possibility. However the test in your question, that's not right. You're testing whether a mocked repository returns a mocked result, which would be like testing whether `1+1=2`.

Comment: it's just for demo purposes, of course that test doesn't make sense

Comment: @Kayaman I disagree. His test is checking that the method loads the entity and returns the result of the `getName()` method call on the entity. Using a mock for this in no way affects the validity of the test.

Comment: @Captain of course it affects. It's testing whether a fake repository returns a fake object. That would be testing the test harness, not your code. But as OP said, it was an example.

Comment: @radzserg I wouldn't even make this a unit test. I'd use a test database and make an integration test instead. Easier to create and change test data, no need for excessive mocking of things like repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply mock the entity.

```
        @Test
        public void test() {

            String productName = "w00t!";
            long productId = 1L;

            Product product = mock(Product.class);
            doReturn(productName).when(product).getName();

            doReturn(product)
                    .when(productsRepository)
                    .findById(productId);

            String name = myAwesomeService.returnProductName(productId);

            assertThat(name).isEqualTo(productName);
        }
```

It is a bit strange though to see your entity with only the default constructor, and no setters. Such an entity could only be used as a read only entity. Your application code could never insert a new Product or update the fields of an existing one.

Comment: I build a microservice that uses existing DB. It only reads from it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful...

```
@Mock Product productMock;
@Mock ProductRepository productRepoMock;

@Test
public void validateEntityMock() {
   given(productMock.getName()).willReturn("name");
   given(productRepoMock.findOne(anyInt())).willReturn(productMock);

   // assert the results...
}
```